# How to fix NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED on AWS ACM / ELB in Chrome / Firefox

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, aws-acm

I am posting this here to help others facing this problem as I could not find any useful information on the web.

If you have mapped your ACM certificate to an end-point (EC2, ELB, EKS service.. whatever) You will need to enable

> CertificateTransparencyLoggingPreference

Else you will get:

> NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED

Error in chrome. To do this via the aws-cli, the command is:

```
aws acm update-certificate-options --certificate-arn <ARN of ACM certificate> --options CertificateTransparencyLoggingPreference=ENABLED
```

I have provided the full response from AWS support as the answer, as this contains even more information.

Answer (score -2):

> This is Vivek from AWS Containers team. I will assist you on this
> case.
>
> From the case description, I understand that you requested an ACM
> certificate and created ELB(service load balancer) behind which you
> are running nginx pods in EKS cluster example-EKS-CLUSTER-dev.
>
> When accessing the site https://test-aws.example.co/  from browser you
> are getting error as below:
>
> Error: NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED
>
> You would like to use a third party CA such as lets encrypt to issue
> free SSL certificate for your domains. You do not want to move the
> domain to Route53.
>
> You wish to know how to to do this and achieve https.
>
> Please let me know if my understanding is correct.
>
> Regarding the error ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED, this error
> is thrown by Chrome browser when it can not find CT(certificate
> transparency) logs.
>
> For Google Chrome to trust the certificate, all issued or imported
> certificates must have the SCT information embedded in them.
>
> By default ACM logs all new and renewed certificates. However, it
> provides option to opt out from AWS API or CLI.
>
> You may find more about this on link [1].
>
> I checked the load balancer mapped to the domain “test-aws.example.co”.
> It is mapped to ELB
> abce6962e05794f36a23435db3f1837d-1755308045.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
> which uses ACM certificate
> arn:aws:acm:eu-west-2:150737547637:certificate/f932b11d-af17-4023-be41-045c6fcc5e86
>
> I checked this certificate and found that the option
> “CertificateTransparencyLoggingPreference” is disabled.
>
> You may enable transparency on the certificate to fix the issue by
> running following command:
>
> aws acm update-certificate-options --certificate-arn  --options
> CertificateTransparencyLoggingPreference=ENABLED
>
> Once the certificate is updated with
> CertificateTransparencyLoggingPreference as enabled, the issue will
> resolve i.e. you should not longer receive the error
> NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED when accessing the site
> over https.
>
> Regarding your other query, i.e. how to use a third party certificate
> such as LetsEncrypt with ELB for https, you may obtain the desired
> certificate(get it issued from desired CA) and import it in ACM or
> IAM. Once the third party certificate is imported in ACM/IAM, it can
> be associated with the https listener of ELB similar to how you
> associate certificate issued by ACM(by using annotation
> service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert in service
> definition yaml with value as the ARN of imported certificate).
>
> Please find the steps to import certificate in ACM on link [2]. The
> steps to import a certificate in IAM can be found on [3].